# Updating matrix makes my site go blank

Tags: matrix, upgrade, updating, update, blank-screen

I've just updated EE to 2.5.5 only to find that matrix images aren't showing. Apparently I need to update matrix from 2.1.2 to 2.5.3 to solve this, but when I do all of the site's pages go blank. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Hey ninjachicken1 - I'm sorry I missed this!  Do you have this in a dev environment where you can upgrade to 2.5.3 and we can troubleshoot without impacting your live site?

Comment: I think you actually solved this when I contacted you through support - pretty sure you said it was a ghost issue.

Comment: Aha, so you're up and running then?  Excellent.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to trigger Matrix's update script. Go to **Add-Ons** → **Fieldtypes** → **Matrix** and it'll run automatically.

If that doesn't work, try turning on error messages for admins and see if that gives you some hints. In `system/expressionengine/config/config.php`, put `$config['debug'] = "1";`

Comment: Already done the first part, but thanks for telling me about the config file. I'd tried that yesterday and thought the site was broken.